# JTextArea: Counting Characters

Tags: java

Eclipse | Netbeans | jdk 1.7

Hi all

It is required to count the Characters of a JTextArea; easy task with an accountant. However, you also have to consider the possibility of deleting Characters with Backspace; and this is where the problem arises that at a certain moment when there are no longer Characters and you keep pressing Backspace, the account is shown in negative.

**How to correctly count Characters and avoid negative accounting?**

Thank you very much already

Comment: Can you share what you have got already?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you did it that you ran into issues or what exactly you did. But since you didn't want to share code, here is a snippet which does what you asked for: counting the characters in the `JTextArea`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            buildGui();
        }
    });
}

private static void buildGui() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    JLabel labelCounter = new JLabel("# of chars: 0");
    textArea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        // When a key press is registered, notify the label
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            labelCounter.setText("# of chars: " + textArea.getText().length());
        }
    });
    panel.add(labelCounter);
    panel.add(textArea);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```